# Add a draggable image view to an existing relative view

Tags: android, imageview

At the moment I have the below code. It adds an imageview to an existing background. However after the image is created the programme crashes when I try to drag it... Anyone got any ideas as to why it doesn't work?

```
ballbutton.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            iv.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ball));
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.resistorbutton);
            iv.setLayoutParams(lp);
            iv.setOnTouchListener(new myListener());
            relativeLayout.addView(iv);
        }
    });
```

The log is as follows:

--------- beginning of crash

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.dan.ball, PID: 2795
                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.ViewGroup.invalidate()' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at com.example.dan.circuit.ball$myListener.onTouch(MainActivity.java:77)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9290)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2403)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2765)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2364)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9514)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5922)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5857)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6025)
                                                                                  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
                                                                                  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                                                                                  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: please post your logcat

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I managed to solve this myself. In my myListener class I was using invalidate() to redraw the view which I didn't need.